# Java Regular Expression to Match Exact Word with Special Characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I have list of keywords entered by the user and they may contains the special characters like `$, #, @, ^, &,` etc.

As per my requirement when ever i receive list of text messages i need to search for all the keywords in every message.

We need to **match exact keyword**.

**CASE 1: Simple Keyword - Simple Message**

I used `\b` to match exact keyword and it ***works*** fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String patternStr =  "(?i)\\bHello\\b";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        strList.add("HHello Message");
        strList.add("This is Hello Message ");
        strList.add("Now Hellos again.");

        for(String str : strList) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            System.out.println(">> "+matcher.find());
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT as Expected**

```
>> false
>> true
>> false
```

**CASE 2 : Simple Keyword - Message with Special Character**

Now, if i run above same code for following messages then it ***didn't work*** as expected.

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("#Hello Message");
strList.add("This is Hello Message ");
strList.add("Now Hellos again.");
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
true
true
false
```

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
false
true
false
```

**CASE 3 : Keyword & Message with Special Character**

If i receive following messages and Keyword is `#Hello`.
I wrote following code but it **didn't work**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String patternStr =  "(?i)\\b#Hello\\b";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        strList.add("HHello Message");
        strList.add("This is #Hello Message ");
        strList.add("Now Hellos again.");

        for(String str : strList) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            System.out.println(">> "+matcher.find());
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>> false
>> false
>> false
```

**Expected OUTPUT:**

```
>> false
>> true
>> false
```

How can i escape the special characters and resolve `CASE 2 and CASE 3`.

Please help.

Comment: A word boundary does not mean a space boundary. This is where you are confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case 2 seems the opposite as case 3, so I don't think you can combine the `Pattern`s.

For case 2, your `Pattern` could look like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)Hello(\\s|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

In this case we surround the keyword by whitespace or beginning/end of input.

For case 3, your `Pattern` could look like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\$#@\\^&]Hello(\\s|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

In this case, we precede the keyword with any of the special characters of your choice (note the escaped reserved characters `$` and `^`), then we accept whitespace or the end of input as the character following the keyword.

Comment: I combined both the patterns as below Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)"+Pattern.quote(phrase)+"(\\s|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); and it worked !!!

Answer (score 3):

Use `(?:^|\s)` ("start of text or whitespace") instead of the first `\b`, and `(?:$|\s)` ("end of text or whitespace") instead of the second `\b` in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the way that "exact word" is defined. It is not just whitespace that can surround the word to make it a word. For example in most circumstances one would want an exact word match for 'Hello' to work with.

"hello there", "That young man just said hello to that other young man" and "I wish people would still answer the telephone by saying ahoy rather than Hello."

If you want the match to be only split on whitespace then I believe you will have to specify the whitespace condition. Assuming you also want to it to match at the end then I would propose something like this.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\(^\| \)" + escapeSearchString(patternString) + "\( \|$\)");
```

and then have a couple of methods like this

```
public String escapeSearchString(String patternString) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(patternString.length() * 3);
    for (char c : patternString.toCharArray()) {
        if (isEscapableCharacter(c)) {
            stringBuilder.append("\\");
        }
        stringBuilder.append(c);
    }
}

public boolean isEscapableCharacter(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '#':
        case '$':
        case '@':
        case '^':
        case '&':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

It would probably be better to iterate over a char[] for the escapable characters and load them from a config file.

Answer (score 1):

Try maybe this way

```
String patternStr = "(?i)(?<=\\s|^)"+Pattern.quote(searchedStubstring)+"(?=\\s|$)";
```

(?<=...) and (?=...) is positive [look behind and ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) so it will check if before your `searchedStubstring` will have

- white-space `\\s` or start of the input `^` before, and
- white-space `\\s` or end of the input `&` after it.

Also in case you would like to searched for special characters like `$` `+` and others you need to escape them. To do this you can use `Pattern.quote(searchedStubstring)`

Answer (score 0):

for example if your word want to have special char (for example here '#') at the begining and end of this you have to write the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^|#)"+word+"(\\s|\\#|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

if you want exact match:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)"+word+"(\\s|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

with '|' is like OR so you can add as match special char's you want ..for example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^|#|:|-)"+word+"(\\s|\\#|\\,|\\.|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

char '^' means to detect the string at beginning of line and '$' means at end of line.
see more here: 
[Summary of regular-expression constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)